# Android: получить контекст Activity после открытия Activity

Tags: android, kotlin

Подскажите плиз, как получить контекст активити  классе Application. В методе notificationOpened я пытаюсь загрузить страницу в webview.Для этого я создаю intent, который проверяет запущена ли активити, и если нет, создает ее. Когда активити уже запущена ссылку на нее получить удается, но если нет,получается null pointer exception, потому что строка currentActivity=(c.getApplicationContext() as App).getCurrentActivity()!!  выполняется вперед метода onCreate(), я так думаю по крайней мере.
Вопрос в следующем:Как получить ссылку на активити после запуска этой активити?
**Класс App:**

```html
class App() : Application() {


private val mCallbacks: MyActivityLifecycleCallbacks = MyActivityLifecycleCallbacks()


  
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(mCallbacks)
    Log.d("123", "app " + applicationContext.toString())

    OneSignal.setLogLevel(OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.VERBOSE, OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.NONE)
    // OneSignal Initialization
    OneSignal.initWithContext(this)
    OneSignal.setAppId(ONESIGNAL_APP_ID)
    OneSignal.setNotificationOpenedHandler()


    { result ->
       Log.d("123", "app pushka")
       val s:String=result.notification.launchURL
   }
}




class MyActivityLifecycleCallbacks() : Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
    var currentActivity: Activity? = null


    override fun onActivityCreated(activity: Activity, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        currentActivity = activity
        Log.d("123", "OnCreate"+currentActivity.toString())


    }

    override fun onActivityStarted(activity: Activity) {
        currentActivity = activity
        Log.d("123","OnStart"+ currentActivity.toString())

    }

    override fun onActivityResumed(activity: Activity) {
        currentActivity = activity
        Log.d("123", currentActivity.toString())

    }

    override fun onActivityPaused(activity: Activity) {
        currentActivity = activity
        Log.d("123", currentActivity.toString())

    }

    override fun onActivitySaveInstanceState(activity: Activity, outState: Bundle) {

    }

    override fun onActivityStopped(activity: Activity) {

    }

    override fun onActivityDestroyed(activity: Activity) {

    }
}


}
```

Comment: Добавь ActivityLifecycleCallbacks в App

Comment: Я попробовал добавить данный слушатель, но теперь он реагирует не только на activity но и на NotificationOpenedReceiver.Т.е. при выполнении кода внутри OneSignal.setNotificationOpenedHandler() он также реагирует. вызывается onActivityCreated, но мне нужно чтобы слушатель срабатывал только на Activity. Куда далее следует копать или мой код в корне не верен, и я не так понял?